# Auto-mount of the contained disk-image, when the external disk is mounted

Tags: macos, external-disk, mount, automount, sparsebundle

I have one external SSD drive that automatically mounts a partition *Backup*.
Inside *Backup* there is a sparse-bundle disk image called *TimeMachine*.

*Backup* is not mounted to `/Volume` but to a specific folder (synced with a cloud service), via `/etc/fstab`:

```
UUID=4E5D0103-741G-46DA-A79E-F923E5C951D1 /Users/myuser/Cloud\040Folder/Backup apfs rw 0 2
```

*How can I trigger the automatic mount of `TimeMachine`, when detecting that `Backup` has been mounted?*

---

Something like `hdiutil attach /Users/myuser/Cloud\040Folder/Backup/TimeMachine.sparsebundle`, being run when detecting that **/Users/myuser/Cloud\040Folder/Backup** is present.

Maybe the `/etc/auto_master` file might help? (I've never used it before)

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the relevant `fstab` _entry_ and actual real world  _pathnames/filenames_ germane to the issue.

Comment: Originally, before my first comment, you had the `hdiutil` _command_ using the `-mountpoint` _option_, i.e. `hdiutil attach  /Volume/A/B.dmg  -mountpoint ~/myMountedB` -- Are you no longer using the  `-mountpoint` _option_? If you are, please edit the question with the missing information.   Also, your current `hdiutil` _command_ isn't valid as having `\040` in `Cloud\040Folder` will return `hdiutil: attach failed - No such file or directory`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the other answer is a bit devoid of explicit/specific details, this is meant to show how it can be done.

In `/etc/fstab` I've added the appropriate *entry* to have the *target disk* containing the `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` *file* automatically mount to the *target location*, when inserted, as shown in your post.

As it's not clear yet you are using the `-mountpoint` with `hdiutil` the following assumes your not, since you removed it, however I will update the `bash` *code* as necessary, if need be.

I have tested the following *steps* and *code*, **and it works**, to automatically have the `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` *file* mounted when the *target disk* containing it is mounted.

**1. Create the `bash` *script* that will be executed whenever a disk is mounted.**

In **Terminal**:

```
cd /Users/Shared
mkdir bin
cd bin
touch MountTimeMachineSparseBundle
open -e MountTimeMachineSparseBundle
```

- Copy and paste the *example* `bash` *code* into the opened document, replacing `_you_` in the `hdiutil` *command* with your *short user name*, save and close.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "Cloud Folder/Backup" == "$(mount | grep -o "Cloud Folder/Backup")" ]; then
    if [ "/Volumes/TimeMachine" !=  "$(mount | grep -o "/Volumes/TimeMachine")" ]; then
        hdiutil attach "/Users/_you_/Cloud Folder/Backup/TimeMachine.sparsebundle"
    fi
fi
```

- Back in **Terminal**, make the `bash` *script* executable:

```
chmod +x MountTimeMachineSparseBundle
```

**2. Create the `.plist` *file* the `daemon` will use to *execute* the `bash` *script* used to automatically have the `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` *file* mounted when the target drive containing it is mounted.**

In **Terminal**:

```
cd /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo nano com.my.MountTimeMachineSparseBundle.plist
```

- Copy and paste the *example* **PLIST XML** *code* into `nano`, save it (**^O Enter**), and exit `nano` (**^X**).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.MountTimeMachineSparseBundle </string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/Shared/bin/MountTimeMachineSparseBundle</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>StartOnMount</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then:

```
sudo chmod 0444 com.my.MountTimeMachineSparseBundle.plist
sudo launchctl load com.my.MountTimeMachineSparseBundle.plist
```

---

**Now when the *target disk* containing the `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` *file* is *mounted*, the `TimeMachine.sparsebundle` *file* will also be *mounted*.**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a launchd LaunchDaemon definition with the key “StartOnMount” set to true. This will allow you to have your own script run whenever something is mounted.

Your own script should then just check if “Backup” is mounted without “TimeMachine” being mounted - and if so, mount “TimeMachine”.

You can use the “mount” command to get information on the currently mounted file systems.